# Javascript: cookie doesn't expire

Tags: drupal, cookies

I'm trying to expire a cookie right after it has set, due to cookielaw restrictions in UK and NL.
Here is the code I now use:

```
(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (!CookieControl.maySendCookies()) {

        var now = new Date();
        var expirationDate = new Date();
        expirationDate.setDate(now.getDate() - 7);
        alert(getCookieValue('has_js'));
        document.cookie='has_js=1;expires=' + expirationDate.toGMTString();
        alert(getCookieValue('has_js'));
    }

});

})(jQuery);
```

The `getCookieValue` function is a function from another document to check it the cookie is actually gone. Before I expire the cookie, the value is `1`, as it should be. However, when I have expired the cookie by using `document.cookie='has_js=1;expires=' + expirationDate.toGMTString();` I check the value again, and it is still there.

I seriously cannot figure out why it is not being removed. I cannot wait for sessions or whatever to expire, that is not according to NL law.

Anyone any suggestions?

CMS: Drupal / Domain: localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be related to path, i don't know, but you can use below scripts:

```
function getCookieValue(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
            return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}

function setCookieValue(name, value, days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

function delCookieValue(name) {
    Set_Cookie(name, '', -1);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!CookieControl.maySendCookies()) {
       delCookieValue("has_js");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mahyar, thanks for the reply. I picked your script, looks more decent then my normal document.cookie. But no difference in the result. However, I figured out it had to do with the browser I was testing with. Firefox apparently only realtime shows cookies being added, but doesn't show realtime changes or deletions. So it worked already all along.

Comment: Hi, you can clear all cookies of problematic browser and try it once more. you can use [How to Clear Your Browser's Cookies](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cookies) if it helps